# how to disable specific date in angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular ui bootsrap datepicker with this version (2.5.0): 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

I want to disable specific dates. for example, every 29th and 30th on each month. how can i do it?

Comment: have you tried `date-disabled` attribute with some function `"disabledDates(date,mode)"`?

Comment: thank you @AlekseySolovey! it's works! i have tried it before but not in the right way. after i made some more research i had discovered how to do it right. to me it works with: date-disabled: vm.disableFN. (withe out parentheses and parameters). after that i define the function like this "vm.disableFN = function(data){ let date = data.date; let mode = data.mode;} the date and the mode sitting within the same object (data).